# Hibernate - Many To Many wants persist data again

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, persist

I have User class, where I want ManyToMany relation referencing on itself - particalury I am solving that user could follows/be followed another user. There is no need for other attributes, so it should be one table with composite primary key. This is how it is annotated:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_followers", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "follower") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "following") })
private Set<User> following = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following")
private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<User>();
```

Everything looks fine - table is generated, PK is composite *follower_following*. When I persist data on first try, it works - insert statement is executed. BUT on the second time, it is still trying to insert previously executed relation (obviously not the same relation) and I get:

```
Unexpected RuntimeException
Last cause: Duplicate entry 'follower-following' for key 'PRIMARY' 
// EDIT: There are correct FK keys instead of follower-following
```

This is how I add follower and persist user:

```
if (!user.following.contains(toFollowUser)) {
   user.following.add(toFollowUser);
}

if (session.contains(user)) {
    session.persist(user);
} else {
    session.merge(user)
}
session.getTransaction().commit(); // HERE I get exception
```

From my point of view, it looks like Hibernate doesn't see that previous relation was peristed and written to database and still try to insert new record that of course falls on duplicated key. Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be unrelated, but "if (session.contains(user) -> persist" is wrong, if the session already contains the object, the object is attached so you dont need to call persist on it (just changing the object will cause the changes to be flushed once commit is called). BTW, what do you mean by first and second time? different transactions? same transaction?

Comment: It means different transaction, it is divided by HTTP Request (I am using Wicket). First one is executed and closed, second one follows.